# Lucene.Net NGramAnalyzer producing query with quoted ngrams e.g [ titleNGram:"his ist sto tor ory" ] instead of [ titleNGram:his ist sto tor ory]

Tags: c#, lucene.net

Following

https://github.com/Sitecore/autohaus/blob/master/Autohaus.Custom/Indexing/Analyzers/NGramAnalyzer.cs

I created this custom Analyzer

```
public class NGramAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    private readonly Version _version;
    private readonly int _minGram;
    private readonly int _maxGram;

    public NGramAnalyzer(Version version, int minGram = 2, int maxGram = 8)
    {
        _version = version;
        _minGram = minGram;
        _maxGram = maxGram;
    }

    public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        // Splits words at punctuation characters, removing punctuation.
        // Splits words at hyphens, unless there's a number in the token...
        // Recognizes email addresses and internet hostnames as one token.
        var tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(_version, reader);

        TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter(tokenizer);

        // Normalizes token text to lower case.
        filter = new LowerCaseFilter(filter);

        // Removes stop words from a token stream.
        filter = new StopFilter(true, filter, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);

        return new NGramTokenFilter(filter, _minGram, _maxGram);

    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that it produces a query in the form

```
[ titleNGram:"his ist sto tor ory" ] instead of [ titleNGram:his ist sto tor ory]
```

For [history]. Note the quotes on the first one

How do I go about making it not quote the query.

I found a similar discusion for Java Lucene here

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=999916&view=next

Is there a way I can fix this without resulting to the workaround.

I am using a PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper and it seems that using the workaround is not going to be clean.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use an `NGramAnalyzer` in my own autocomplete implementation, and this is the only attempt at producing what I was looking for that I could find, so this is where I started.

I had the same issue you describe, and have come up with a fairly clean workaround.

The cause appears to be in `Query GetFieldQuery(String field, String queryText)` at QueryParser.cs:494. This is eventually called as part of `QueryParser.Parse`. If there is more than one token to be added to the query ("his", "ist", and so on being more than one token) and a boolean called `severalTokensAtSamePosition` is false, then `GetFieldQuery` constructs a phrase query (at line 677) and adds all the tokens to it (line 705) before returning.

What we want is for all the tokens to be added to a boolean query, with `Occur.SHOULD`. I attempted to subclass `QueryParser` and override `GetFieldQuery`, as it's marked `virtual`. However, I would've needed to duplicate the rest of the functionality, and found that there were quite a few references to `private` variables. Instead, I figured out how to extract the tokens from the parsed query and insert them into a `BooleanQuery` before running the search:

```
var query = new BooleanQuery();

foreach( var word in terms ) {
    var parsed = parser.Parse( word );

    var extractedTerms = new HashSet<Term>();
    parsed.ExtractTerms( extractedTerms );
    foreach( var term in extractedTerms ) {
        query.Add( new TermQuery( term ), Occur.SHOULD );
    }
}

var resultDocs = searcher.Search( query, maxResults ).ScoreDocs;
```

This seems to work. I'm still working on determining the best values for `minGram` and `maxGram` as well as the best way to deal with terms of length less than `minGram`, but this is a good start.